# Efficient method of dividing every element of an double array by a constant in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

For an Array in scala

```
var mole_array = Array(2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Is there a single command that lets me divide every element of mole_array with a constant without putting it into an explicit for loop . Like we have for sum

```
var molesum = mole_array.reduceLeft[Int](_+_)
```

So example `mole_array /2 = Array( 1,0.5,0,0,0,0)`

Comment: Elaborate your question by giving example. And what do you want as output for that particular example?

Comment: Something like `mole_array.map(_ / 42)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required answer

```
scala> (1 to 10).toArray
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> (1 to 10).toArray.map(_ /2.toDouble)
res3: Array[Double] = Array(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0)
```

Comment: you should be doing `(1 to 10).toArray.map(_ /2.toDouble)`